# How to expand an onItemSelectedListener from a Custom View?

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, custom-controls

The custom view listen to the spinner and change the background and the header of the box, if the user choose an value, which is not the first:

```
//Listener, if the user choose a item in the spinner
sp_First.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}

    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {
            //Is not empty
            if(sp_First.selectedItemId.toInt() != 0) {
                ll_elementFirst.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.border_green_padding, null)
                txt_titleFirst.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#007F0E"))
            } else {
                ll_elementFirst.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.border_padding, null)
                txt_titleFirst.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#949494"))
            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfect. But, I want in the Activity add another onItemSelectedListener, which do something if the choosen value is the third in the list. If I do this, I must overwrite the "onItemSelected"-Method and losing the background/text color-change.

Is there a good solution to expand the onItemSelected-Method?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried something and think, this is the solution:

I outsoured the actions in a seperate method in the class of the CustomView, call it at "onItemSelected" and in the class of my view, I created a new "AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener"-object within I call the seperated method and my new instructions.

DualSpinner.kt

```
//Listener, if the user choose a item in the spinner
sp_First.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}

    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
        seperatedMethod()
    }
}

fun seperatedMethod() {
    //Is not empty
    if(sp_Second.selectedItemId.toInt() != 0) {
        ll_elementSecond.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.border_green_padding, null)
        txt_pleasechooseSecond.visibility = View.GONE
        txt_titleSecond.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#007F0E"))
    } else {
        ll_elementSecond.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.border_padding, null)
        txt_pleasechooseSecond.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        txt_titleSecond.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#949494"))
    }

    //Is the other element also not empty?
    if(sp_First.selectedItemId.toInt() != 0 && sp_Second.selectedItemId.toInt() != 0) {
        ll_main.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.border_green_padding, null)
        txt_title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#007F0E"))
    } else {
        ll_main.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.border_padding, null)
        txt_title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#949494"))
    }
}
```

Activity.kt

```
sp_MARKFLR.sp_Second.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {
            sp_MARKFLR.seperatedMethod()

            if(sp_MARKFLR.sp_First.selectedItem.toString().contains("ohne Markierung")) {
                sp_MARKFLRZ.setSelection(1, 1)
            }

        }
    }
```